# Replacing / adding to a folder in OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

I am quite new to OS X and I just dragged a folder from one Finder window to another and it said that it already existed, and asked me whether I wanted to replace it – and I said yes.

The outcome was strange coming from a Windows background. The two folders originally had the same name and inside the folder there were a number of other folders. Finder seemed to do exactly that: *replacing* the folder with the one I was copying. It didn't add anything to it.

Is this correct?

Any way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Finder seemed to do exactly that: *replacing* the folder with the one I was copying. It didn't add anything to it. Is this correct?

If you simply move the folder to its destination, e.g. by dragging and dropping it, you get the standard *Replace* dialog:

[image]

If you click *Replace* here, you'll end up entirely removing the old folder, replacing it with the new one. True, OS X does what it promises here. This is not what you'd expect coming from Windows, but it's the default OS X behavior.

However, if you copy the folder, e.g. by selecting *File » Copy…* or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, and then paste it to the destination with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, you get a new option for merging the contents – and this is what you'd usually want to do:

[image]